# How to reset sequence of animations when target is lost

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am using Unity and Vuforia, and would like to make an animation on AR object that starts when target is found and resets when target is lost so that, when target is found again the animation starts from the beginning.

In order to make animation start only once target is found, I selected the option "Cull Completely" in the Culling Mode property of the animator component. But I can't manage to reset the animation when target is lost ! I have tried modifying the DefaultTrackableEventHandler script (the OnTrackingFound and OnTrackingLost methods) but it doesn't work.

So far I have tried :

```
Animation[] animationComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Animation>();
foreach (Animation component in animationComponents)
{
    component.Stop();
}
```

and some variations (animation name as a parameter of Stop method, animator component instead of animation component, ...).

Does someone know how to do this ?

Thanks for your attention :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know a way of doing what you want in a simpler way. Look for https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-State.html

You will get the same results but in a different way using the animation states.

[image: Animator Controller]

Then go to the animator window

[image: Animator Windows]

And you can build something like that. Those are transitions between states, associated to an animation.

[image: Animations, Transitions and More]

Take a look at this too https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Transition.html

So in your script you can access to the Animator with:

```
Animator MyAnimator = GetComponent<Animator>();
```

And in somewhere over your conditions in the game, you can do this:

```
MyAnimator.Play("Attack");
```

If that animation doesn't have a transition, it will your decision to make it a loop animation (it will repeat when ends) or it will stay in the position of the last frame of the animation.

With some conditions you might want to have, like the one in your question, you could do something like this.

```
if (Vector3.Distance(this.transform.position, myTarget.transform.position) >= 2f) {
  MyAnimator.Play("Idle");
}
```

Warning: That Vector3.Distance may not be the best and fastest way of doing it, it's just as an example. Remember to always try to optimize your code with your project requirements.

Comment: I just used the MyAnimator.Play part : when target is found, I play the first animation of the sequence. It is working just like I wanted it to, but is it the right way to do this or should have I used something like Vector3.Distance() ? Thanks a lot for your answer, helped me a lot :)